# MySQL, MongoDB and Solr

Tags: mysql, mongodb, solr

I'm not so familiar with NoSQL databases, and I'm not quite aware of their potential, and I'm still learning. In meantime, I need to develop simple application with search capabilities.

I've read a few posts about Solr, MongoDB and combination of these. But, the application I have to create, should include many "standard" things (like Combo boxes, which should be populated from database). Also, there are fields for metadata, and other additional info.

The idea I thought about is to develop MySQL database which will keep relational data (like metadata, combobox values, notes...). For every record, I could generate ID which should be forwarded to Solr, together with document which should be indexed. Solr will do indexing, and that document, with assigned ID could be stored in MongoDB.

Probably there is an easier way, and I would like to hear that :) this is not that hard, but I'm not sure that is the best way. At the end of the day, application should be fairly simple: user should choose few predefined fields, enter few more fields and upload a document (or few of them). If someone could suggest better architecture, please, I would appreciate an advice.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start from document structure.

> But, the application I have to create, should include many "standard"
>   things (like Combo boxes, which should be populated from database).
>   Also, there are fields for metadata, and other additional info.

I sounds like mongodb very good fit for data you want to store, because you can keep all related to combobox data within single document on mongodb and it will be very naturally. In mysql for all referenced things like notes, values you will probably use separate tables.

This is an example of potential schema in mongodb:

```
{
 _id : 1,
 name : "andrew",
  values: [
       {_id: 1,
       name: "test 1"},
       {_id: 2,
       name: "test 2"},
   ],
  metadata: {
    storeDate: someDate, 
    anyOtherMetadata: ""
  },
  notes: [
    {_id: 1, "note 1"},
    {_id: 2, "note 2"},
  ]
}
```

If your app should have full text search you can store information twice on each update/insert. First in mongodb and second in solr. Also in sort you can have document that you need to display to the end user (it usually not contains all information that contains document in a database):

solr document:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "andrew",
  searchField: "here you can store all staff on what you want search"
}
```

Solr document _id correspondent to mongodb document _id.

So:

1. With above schema when you need search you simple populate data from solr
2. But when you need show details of particular document you load it from mongodb by solr _id.

And in general i don't see in your application place for mongodb, mysql and solr together.

I see only two reasonable combinations:

1. mongodb + solr
2. mysql + solr

Comment: Thank you Andrew! The point of MySQL was the fact that I didn't know what I can do using MongoDB. I've just start learning about it. Answer is really detailed and it helps a lot. It will be MongoDB and Solr.
I will filter documents according to data stored in mongodb ("give me all documents with name starting with..." etc), and search using solr. Just like you said, it should be easy to read document from mongodb based on id which is provided by solr.
Thank you again.